# How to find twitter trends based on location?

Tags: twitter, location

I'm trying to build a trendsmap sort of an application. trendsmap.com
So far I have used twitters streaming api to get the tweets and I am filtering these based on geocoordinates since this returns only geotagged tweets. I am storing these into couchdb.
No I need to find the most trending topics based on locations.
I cant figure out how to do this?
Is my approach right?
Twitter trends api gives only the most top ten trending tweets with a woeid or the world. and atmost 30 daily most trending tweets. I need to find the tweets that are trending based on location and then map them onto some visualization.
Can anyone help me with any idea?

Comment: There are entire companies that specialize in doing this, and you expect us to answer this in a SO answer? :-)

Comment: I liked the idea and wanted to do it as a college project. Maybe not on a large scale like they have. I just asked the approach. I don't see what is so bad in this.

Comment: Trend analysis via the stream API isn't exactly trivial. You have to scan every tweet and analyze it to find out what it's about. Then you have to group those by subject and determine which subjects are used most. Those are the trends.

Comment: Thank you.:) Ok supposing I have a way to do it. How do I say this set of tweets are from this locations?

Comment: Look at the user's location field and the tweet's geo data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use Java you could use [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org) and get trends like so...

```
public List<String> getTrends(AccessToken atoken) throws TwitterException{
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(atoken);
    Trends trends = twitter.getLocationTrends(1);
    List<String> currentTrends = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Trend t: trends.getTrends()){
        String name = t.getName();
        currentTrends.add(name);
    }
    return currentTrends;
}
```

That about functions returns the current trends world wide. You simply change the `getLocationTrends()`argument with a different [woeid](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/02/woeids-in-twitters-trends.html) to get the trends for that area. If you're looking to map particular tweets onto precise areas you'd filter your tweets to only return those with geolocations tagged.

If you're not using Java just use the [Twitter API directly](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/%3awoeid) on an alternative library. The same process applies.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im currently using python.But the reason I didnt use this is because it gives me only top ten trends.
And also when you specify the woeid , what is the maximum granularity that I can expect this api to work with.